# Qt Windowing System?

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, windowing

I just started using QWS. I am looking for more details about Qt Windowing System(QWS) but the resources are really few. I have read this one http://www.slideshare.net/qtbynokia/qt-on-real-time-operating-systems but I think it only covered few things. I would like to understand how the server and clients interact with each other and the other things that's happening in QWS. I hope someone could guide me. Thank you.